# Using a dataclass to read a text file setting an attribute to be a datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to force myself to get into the habit of using dataclasses. I'm reading a text file with rows of data, two of the columns contain a date. When I read the file into the class, why is the date not being converted to a datetime object?

```py
import datetime
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class AC07:
    NAME: str
    MADE_FROM_DATE: datetime.datetime
    MADE_UPTO_DATE: datetime.datetime
    
counter = 0
deck = []
with open(filename, encoding="latin-1") as file:
    for line in file:
        args = line.strip().split("|")[1:]  # not interested in first column
        data = AC07(*args)
        deck.append(data)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
            break
        
print (type(deck[0].MADE_FROM_DATE))
<class 'str'>
# Expected behavior <class datetime.datetime>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please someone correct me if am wrong, but I believe dataclasses does not force type. datetime.datetime in your example is (almost) merely an annotation, apart from two implementation details. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.field). Specifically,

> The dataclass() decorator examines the class to find fields. A field is defined as class variable that has a type annotation. With two exceptions described below, nothing in dataclass() examines the type specified in the variable annotation.

The two exceptions have nothing to do with forcing data types:

> Class variables
> One of two places where dataclass() actually inspects the type of a field is to determine if a field is a class variable as defined in PEP 526. It does this by checking if the type of the field is typing.ClassVar. If a field is a ClassVar, it is excluded from consideration as a field and is ignored by the dataclass mechanisms. Such ClassVar pseudo-fields are not returned by the module-level fields() function.

> Init-only variables
> The other place where dataclass() inspects a type annotation is to determine if a field is an init-only variable. It does this by seeing if the type of a field is of type dataclasses.InitVar. If a field is an InitVar, it is considered a pseudo-field called an init-only field. As it is not a true field, it is not returned by the module-level fields() function. Init-only fields are added as parameters to the generated `__init__()` method, and are passed to the optional `__post_init__()` method. They are not otherwise used by dataclasses.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand it better using the answer posted by @vasco-ludovico, to solve my issues I used the code below:

```py
with open(filename, encoding="latin-1") as file:
    for line in file:
        args = line.strip().split("|")[1:]  # not interested in first column
        data = AC07(*args)
        data.MADE_FROM_DATE = datetime.datetime.strptime(data.MADE_FROM_DATE, "%d/%m/%Y")
        deck.append(data)
        counter += 1
        if counter == 10:
            break
```